# Difference of $R^2$ between OLS with individual dummies to panel fixed effect model?

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, r-squared

Based on my understanding, panel fixed effect model is equivalent to OLS with individual dummies. However, when I ran the two models in R, the $R^2$ from the two models were quite different: 0.8 for OLS with individual dummies and 0.06 for fixed effect model.

Is it the case that in fixed effect model, the fixed effects (individual dummies) are excluded from the calculation of $R^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In essence, yes. The $R^2$ value given for fixed effects regressions is often called the "within $R^2$". If you use stata, the output will give overall, within, and between $R^2$. If you use the `plm` package in R, it just give the within $R^2$. The basic difference between the overall and within $R^2$ is that the within finds the total sum of squares *on the demeaned outcome variable*. Fixed effects regression demeans the *y* for each fixed entity.

For the fixed effects model, $$R^2 = \dfrac{SSR}{TSS_{demeaned \ y}} = \dfrac{\sum(y - \hat y)^2}{\sum([y_i - \bar y_i] - \overline {[y_i -  \bar y_i]})^2}$$

To demonstrate in R using the `EmplUK` data from `plm`:

```r
    > library(plm)
    > data("EmplUK")
    > fixed <- plm(emp ~ wage + capital, data = EmplUK, index= 
         c("firm"), model = "within")
    > fixed.dum <- lm(emp ~ wage + capital + factor(firm) - 1, 
          data = EmplUK)
    > summary(fixed.dum)$r.squared[1] 
  summary(fixed)$r.squared[1] 
    [1] 0.9870826
          rsq 
    0.1635585 
    > 
    
    > #"Within" R2
    > SSR <- sum(fixed$residuals^2)
> demeaned_y <- EmplUK$emp - 
       tapply(EmplUK$emp, EmplUK$firm,mean)[EmplUK$firm]
> TSS_demeaned_y <- sum((demeaned_y-mean(demeaned_y))^2)
> within_R2 <- 1-(SSR/TSS_demeaned_y)
> c(summary(fixed)$r.squared[1], "rsq" = within_R2)
          rsq       rsq 
    0.1635585 0.1635585
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for the three types of R-squared of the Fixed Effects model outputs in R as well.

Thanks to the help of @paqmo, I was able to manually calculate and reproduce **lfe**'s *full* and *proj* R-squared using the model fit from the standard **lm** package. That said, I am quite certain that the *full* R-sq is straightforward, meaning R-sq of all pairs of predicted values and original values. At the same time, their *proj* R-squared is also identical to the so-called *within* R-squared (definitions from [STATA](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1314121-r-squared-within-between-overall)), which is the default reported R-squared in the **plm** package.

After reading STATA [manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/xtxtreg.pdf) Page 10 briefly, I think the *full* R-sq in **lfe** and *overall* R-sq in **STATA** are the same idea. I see some people said overall R-sq is a weighted average of *within* and *between* R-sq, but I did not see any supporting evidence for this statement. I only see that both *overall* and *full* R-sq are directly calculated from the pairs of predicted y and original y.

Below are my own calculations for *full* and *proj* R-sq.

```r
    fe_lm_mod <- lm(formula = "y ~ x1 + x2 + entity - 1", 
       data = dataframe)
    ## Calculate prediction
    y_predict <- predict(fe_lm_mod, newdata = dataframe)
    y_original <- dataframe$y
    
    # Get the valid values indices
    notmiss <- which((!is.na(y_predict)) & (!is.na(y_original))) 

    # Residiual sum of squares
    SSres <- sum((y_original[notmiss] - y_predict[notmiss])**2)

    # Calculate full R2
    SStot_full <- sum((y_original[notmiss] - 
                    mean(y_original[notmiss]))**2)
    
    ### get the demean. The within finds the total sum of 
    ### squares on the demeaned outcome variable. 
    ### References
    # https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262246/difference-of-r2-between-ols-with-individual-dummies-to-panel-fixed-effect-mo
    demeaned_y <- y_original[notmiss] - 
      tapply(y_original[notmiss], dataframe$entity[notmiss], 
     mean)[dataframe$entity][notmiss]
    # Calculate within R2
    SStot_within <- sum((demeaned_y-mean(demeaned_y))^2)

    print(paste("calculated full R2", 1 - SSres/SStot_full))
    print(paste("calculated within R2", 1 - SSres/SStot_within))
```

For *between* R-sq, I think the **plm** package with model="between" may produce *between* R-sq, but I am not very sure. One can try to calculate it based on the STATA manual, like what I did for *full* and *within* R-sq.

So far I made a summary for the R-sq outputs (to be continued):

1. lm R-sq: not good for Fixed Effects model, cannot reproduce
2. lfe "full" R-sq: R-sq for all pairs predicted y and original y, may also be called as "overall" R-sq
3. lfe "proj" R-sq: "within" R-sq: how much of the variation in the dependent variable within each entity group is captured by the model
4. plm model="within" R-sq: same as 3.
5. plm model="between" R-sq: "between" R-sq: how much of the variation in the dependent variable between each entity group is captured by the model
6. plm model="pooling" R-sq: not good for Fixed Effects model. This is the standard OLS R-sq. It is not a Fixed Effects model R-sq.